# How to have Powershell prompt for commands inside a script file?

Tags: powershell, prompt, powershell-core

let's say i have a script file, and in the middle of it (or at the end or whatever) i'd like for the user to be able to access the **current** session as if not running a script, and start writing commands at his will.

I know this is possible, at the end of the script, by running powershell with the `-NoExit` parameter. But:

- you have to manually invoke the powershell/pwsh binary and specify the parameter for every invocation
- you can't do it in the middle of the script

I know i could simply open a new session by executing the powershell binary like this:

```
Some-Command
echo "current PID=$PID" # let's say PID is 12345
$var = 123
& pwsh
Another-Command
```

but i would like to access the *current* session. Meaning that `$PID` is the `12345` during the script, **and** when i'm entering commands. Meaning that i could i access all of the variables with their current values (so i could read `$var` and get `123`), then exit whenever i want, and go on with the script.

I looked into `Enter-PSHostProcess` but it can't connect to the current process, and (apparently) doesn't have access to the variables (i think this is for security reasons).

Is all of this, at all, possible?

thanks

PS: if it's not clear, my intent is not simply to "keep a script open after execution", i know how to do that; and it's not to "prompt for user *input*" (meaning data), i know how to do that

Comment: please also see my own reply below

Answer (score 1):

My best solution by far is

```
while($true){Invoke-Expression $(Read-Host $(prompt))}
 # or
while($true){Invoke-Expression $(Read-Host 'Custom Prompt> ')}
```

which is pretty ugly: as @olaf pointed out, [invoke-expression is to be avoided like hell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.3)

(also i fear that this might not be fully functional in some way? like scoping problems, or piping/interrupt problems, or whatever)

Comment: You may like to read this: [Avoid using Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: @Olaf i know damn well that IEX is bad...  i'll make it clear in the answer itself. i simply found no other solution unluckily

Comment: i mean, it was actually my *last resort* as Microsoft says in the article..

Comment: ```Invoke-Expression``` is definitely bad for *untrusted* / *unsanitised* input, but if the user already has access to your script's source and an interactive powershell command prompt in a console session (which is sounds like they do in this case if they're running the script locally themselves) then it doesn't pose any *additional* risk over what the user could do in the interactive session without your script in the first place...

Comment: mmh yes, security risks are not my main concern as i **want** to give the user access (i'm *the user*). my concerns are about parsing, keyboard interrupts, etc. how does it behave? it is surely not as being inside a standard `& pwsh` session

Comment: One left-field option might be to set a debug breakpoint at the line you want to stop at. Tbh I’ve not done much with breakpoints so it might be a non-starter, but it’s worth a look…

Comment: mmh didn't think of that but it might work. @mclayton i'm adding another answer with this kind of solution, if you want you can also post yours, and eventually i will mark yours as accepted answer if i will resort to breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Totally different possible solution [as suggested here by @mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75983899/how-to-have-powershell-prompt-for-commands-inside-a-script-file/75983900?noredirect=1#comment134019235_75983900), using breakpoints:

```
function debug_break() {}
Get-PSBreakpoint | Remove-PSBreakpoint
Set-PSBreakpoint -Command debug_break


Write-Output '111'
$xxx = 999
debug_break # here i can see $xxx being 999, then i can type "continue" to go on with the script
Write-Output '222'
```